# cURL: Preventing iterations while using multiple globs

Tags: curl

I found very useful instructions about globbing in the cURL documentation. However, I am unable to figure out a way to run the following more efficiently:

To download the images of Ben, Alice and Frank, in the resolutions 100 100, 750 750 and 1000 1000:

`curl http://example.com/{Ben,Alice,Frank}-{100x100,750X750,1000x1000}.jpg -o "subdir/#1_#2"`

Although this works it iterates over each item. For instance, this will result in 9 iterations. What I looking for is a way to tell cURL that I am only interested in images of Ben with a resolution of 100X100, Alice with a resolution of 750X750 and Frank with 1000X1000 ie. 3 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

> What I looking for is a way to tell cURL that I am only interested in images of Ben with a resolution of 100X100, Alice with a resolution of 750X750 and Frank with 1000X1000 ie. 3 iterations.

You don't tell that to cURL at all - the brace expansion is done by the shell.

In order to not multiply the resulting combinations, just don't use two patterns, but rather only one:

```
curl http://example.com/{Ben-100x100,Alice-750X750,Frank-1000x1000}.jpg -o "subdir/#1_#2"
```